# PHP JSON Special Characters

Tags: php, json, encoding

There should return a number of results in my hand json type. But I can not output due to special characters.
Example data in content array:

> Alt�n Portakal Film Festivali sonu�land�.

(Problem: `�` )

```
$JSON["today"]=array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($olay_tarih); $i++) { 
    $gelen["date"] = array();
    $gelen["content"]=array();
    array_push($gelen["date"], $olay_date[$i]);
    array_push($gelen["content"], $olay_content[$i]);
    array_push($JSON["today"], $gelen);
}
echo json_encode($JSON);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid PHP JSON encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790425/invalid-php-json-encoding)

Comment: I could not find the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', true,200);
$JSON["today"]=array();
    
for ($i=0; $i < count($olay_tarih); $i++) { 
$gelen["date"]=array();
$gelen["content"]=array();
array_push($gelen["date"], $olay_date[$i]);
array_push($gelen["content"], $olay_content[$i]);
array_push($JSON["today"], $gelen);
}
$JSON = array_map('utf8_encode', $JSON);
echo json_encode($JSON);
```

Adding UTF-8 headers will make the browser recognize any special characters for this setting.

Comment: Is that we add into the loop?

Comment: I have editted it so you understand where to put it.

Comment: Would you please show on the code? I did not understand

Comment: Sorry, there was improvement

Comment: @PhiterFernandes What does the 200 do in `header()`?

Comment: @CharlieHarding, the 200 is actually the default value for it. It's not necessary. But it's the `http_response_code`, 200 means "OK", as in there is nothing problematic about the page. 404 would mean not found, for example.

Answer (score 5):

What's the output with this?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo(json_encode($JSON, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

> **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**

Encodes multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as `\uXXXX`). Available since PHP 5.4.0.