# jQuery autocomplete special characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an ajax call which is fetching a JSON representation of a value created by a php json_encode method:

```
["Montérégie","Montréal - North Shore ","Montréal - South Shore"]
```

The values are being harvested from a  'controller/ajax_autocomplete' by a  jquery autocomplete box.

```
  $(function(){   $("#regions").autocomplete({               
            source: "controller/ajax_autocomplete",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}                                                          
            });            
    });
```

All values are being corectly picked up by jQuery UI's ui-autocomplete but the special charaters are lost. 
`Montréal become Montr&eacute;al, Montérégie   become Mont&eacute;r&eacute;gie` ...

The special characters are certainly destroyed during http transport because the problem goes away if I manualy copy the JSON table to jquery function.

```
    $(function(){   $("#regions").autocomplete({               
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            source: "["Montérégie","Montréal - North Shore ","Montréal - South Shore"]"
}                                                          
            });            
    });
```

Programmatically decoding the html entity works for text box value but the suggestion list still replaces the special characters with HTML entities

```
$(function(){   $("#regions").autocomplete({              
        source: "controller/ajax_autocomplete",
        select: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.value = $('<div />').html(ui.item.value).text();
        }                                                                                                                                                                                            
        });            
});
```

The solution would be to decode the HTML entities in suggestion list

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/34415506/4802649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue on server side by wrapping the ajax output into php 'html_entity_decode' method.

Answer (score 0):

you should use :

example:

```
var myData = ["Montérégie","Montréal - North Shore ","Montréal - South Shore"];
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myData))
```

Comment: Your example is using a local array and I have already  mentioned in description that the auto-complete works with in such a case. The issue is that special characters are being being encoded into html entities during http transfer from server to client.